# Implementing admob mediation with Facebook audience network inside flutter apps

Tags: flutter, admob, ios14, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I have my flutter app on both google playstore and apple appstore with ads implemented using [facebook_audience_network](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network)

But "Facebook Audience Network will only use bidding to fill ads in iOS apps from 31 March.
"

So i would like to use admob (as they have more documentation) as a mediation with my existing ads in Facebook audience network. But being a novice coder i'm finding it hard to do what's needed as both facebook and admob(for mediation) have their documentation for android/iOS specifically.

It'll be a great help if someone can guide me on how to achieve it.
Also, one need to set the "Advertising tracking enabled" flag to continue effectively monetising your iOS apps. This will inform Facebook whether to use the data to deliver personalised ads.

It'll be a great help if someone can guide me through this. Thank you.

Comment: hi man, I am in the same boat. Have you figured it out what steps are required to migrate to app bidding?

Comment: @letiagoalves not yet. Please update here if you find anything.

Comment: Have you got any solution? @OmkarBojjawar

Comment: hey @YatinjSutariya nope, I instead opted for AdMost mediation which is comparatively much easier.